# Why is a Möbius transform uniquely determined based on known mappings of three points?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can the Möbius transform $\displaystyle{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}}$ be uniquely determined if one is aware that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ maps to $\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$ where $p_1,\dots,q_3\in\Bbb{C}$?

Seeing as there are four unknowns $a,b,c,d$, shouldn't the mappings be known for four points instead of three?

Comment: a,b,c,d is not uniquely determined (even given images of infinitely many points ) but the transformation is.(by taking a=1 wlog and there are 3 variables left)

Answer (score 4):

There is a symmetry.  Double $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$, and you get the same transform.  So there are only three relevant numbers: $a/b$,$a/c$ and $a/d$

Comment: I don't understand. Say I have fixed values for $a,b,c$. I still can choose infinitely many values for $d$! How does the degree of freedom reduce by one here?

Comment: @fierydemon that statement does not contradict empy2's symmetry

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite as $\displaystyle\frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{z+ba^{-1}}{z+dc^{-1}}=A\frac{z+B}{z+C}$

Answer (score 2):

Mobius transformations can be represented by 2 x 2 matrices, given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}
$$
Well, sort of. There is a map $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to Aut(\mathbb{H})$ (where  $Aut(\mathbb{H})$ is the collection of fractional linear transformations), which looks as you say like we should have four real parameters. However, there is a kernel to this map! Specifically, diagonal matrices all map to the identity (which you should check), and so the group of fractional linear transformations is really
$$
M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})/(\lambda \cdot Id) = PSL_2(\mathbb{R})
$$
which is three dimensional. Hence you only need three points to determine a Mobius tranformation.

Comment: What is $\mathbb H$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's the upper half-plane.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(z)$ and $R(z)$ be two Möbius transformations which satisfy
\begin{gather*}
S(q_j) = p_j\\
R(q_j) = p_j.
\end{gather*}

Möbius transformations are rational functions, the transformation
$$S(z) - R(z)$$
has order at most 2, then it can have at most two zeros, but you know it has 3, so $S(z)-R(z)=0$ for all complez $z$.

And that's why 3 points are enough to characterize a Möbius transformations.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is almost immediate if one knows that the set of Möbius transformations (with the composition operation) is a group. This is one of the first results that appears when studying Möbius transformations.

In order to prove your claim, one shows that any Möbius transformation different to identity has at most two fixed points. This claim is trivial and just direct inspection of the equation $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=z$.

Now, suppose that you have two Möbius transformations $M$ and $N$ that coincide at three points. The map $M \circ N^{-1}$ is a Möbius transformation (due to the group property) and it has three fixed points. Due to the previous paragraph, $M \circ N^{-1} = Id$, so $M = N$.